# F# MvcWebApi - Postman - FromBody always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, postman

I have just started to begin playing around with an F# MvcWebApi. I have started with the basic template and have managed to get this working up to the point where I place data in the body of a request from postman. Every time I try and access any values passed from the body they are always null for some reason ie(In the case below data will always be null) can any one help me with this please

ValueController code

```
type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()

   //Always returs null
   member x.Post ([<FromBody>] data:string) = data

   //Works
   member x.Post ([<FromBody>] data:string) = "Succesful"
```

I am using postman to call in to the api
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the "FromBody" Attribute is right for you in this case - have you tried without it (or just set a breakpoint and have a look at the env. variables of your controller, request, ...)

Comment: If I go with out the body I will get an error ""Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50442/api/values'.","

Answer (score 5):

While I don't know *Postman*, it looks as though you're setting `Content-Type` to "application/json" in both cases. When you say that you post "application/json" (or "application/xml"), Web API will attempt to *bind* your structured data to a 'model'.

Have you tried with an F# record instead?

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type DataModel = { data : string }

type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()

    member x.Post (dataModel : DataModel) = x.Ok data
```

You'll also need to [add this statement to your configuration](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/03/19/posting-json-to-an-f-web-api):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <-
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

Comment: Hey Mark I don't have the option of (x.OK), but i tryed member x.Post (dataModel : DataModel) = dataModel.data and thats still null

Comment: @AlanMulligan It's a [method on ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314591.aspx), but I incorrectly remembered the casing. Will fix.

Comment: @AlanMulligan Instead of Postman, can you please post your HTTP request and response as plain text in order to make it easier to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @AlanMulligan That's not much help, but I've updated my answer. If you need more details, follow the links :)

Comment: I'm running into this behavior in .Net Core. However, I don't see a GlobalConfiguration type